# What is the good video equveilent of 1300D?

Tags: video, video-quality, dslr, video-capture, canon

I was surfing the net and I found this [answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/17529).

> Bottom line with the **canon rebel series cameras is that the video is
>   pulled from a low resolution capture of the chip** which is normally
>   used for high resolution photos. The photos from these cameras will
>   resolve many thousands of lines but the video compression chip in the
>   camera cannot deal with these in real time so **they just grab the image**
>   **that goes to the rear LCD screen**.
>
> **This image is achieved by throwing away the** **high res photo lines (or**
>   **pixels), this is called binning (discarding)**. This makes high contrast
>   edges very aliased or have a stair stepped effect. To fix this Canon
>   soften or blur the image to make it more acceptable. Guess what, all
>   of this results in a video image that ends up resolving at about 480
>   vertical lines or standard TV resolution 'not' HD resolution. So no
>   amount of sharp lenses or post sharpening will ix the matter. The soft
>   is baked in

So my question is. What is the cheapest Canon DSLR that doesn't do the crappy "use the LCD viewfinder feed for video capture" stuff but properly records video?

The brand must be Canon

Sensor size must be at least APSC .

The camera must have GPS and WIFI along with an hot shoe.

I don't want something from the last decade and the camera must be max 5 years old.

Budget is not yet decided but will be properly low and second hand is a big possibility.

I want to be flexible and change lenses as I wish also I will shoot all photos in the smallest aperture ppssible because I believe every photo should contain max information and art should be done in the photoshop.

I Will probably just shoot photos but I am interested in shooting videos and probably turning the camera to an makeshift go pro.

Comment: Ypu need to br more specific here. Whats your budget? Do you soley want to shoot video or take photos too? Do you want interchangable lenses? Bokeh?...

Comment: @TimothyLukasH. I didn't buy [force my parents] a DSLR yet. Although photography is my main concern ı want to shoot video too. One more thing. I found the question about the crappy video on DSLR and the question will be edited soon.

Comment: @TimothyLukasH. Complete rewrite done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are asking for a lot of things here.

I'd guess the best option would be a Canon M50, it is not a DSLR camera, but the industry tends away from DSLRs anyway.

It can shoot good 4k footage, is new and also shoots good images. You can get it with a double lens kit for around 900$. You can also adapt it to Canon EF.

She has Connectivity to your phone and as far as I understand GPS over your phone. So no GPS if you ain't connected to it.

> smallest aperture ppssible

I'd guess you're refering to the physical size, so biggest possible aperture number.
I wouldn't suggest that, as many lenses lose sharpness and get color aborations at over F/11.

But this should give you enough DOF anyways.

If you are not satisfied with a mirrorless camera and want for what ever reason to have a DSLR, just write me a comment.

Comment: Absolute minimums I need are wifi\gps\interchangeable lenses\as the bold lines in the quotes area. A dslr that doesn't use the LCD viewfinder video trick that's all I need.alsp all I need is 1080p video. The gps over the phone is cool but I thinl it's a good idea to have GPS embedded to the camera itself. Thanks for the mirror less recommendation by the way.

Comment: The M50 has all the features you want besides the GPS, but as I said it has a work around. I guess it's the best investment for Canon in the below 1000$ mark currently.